# How to find webelement using style property

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Below is the HTML code of an element and I want to locate this element by classs and style property using selenium webDriver in java

```
 <div class="qooxdoo-table-cell" style="left:252px;width:117px;height:24px;"/>
```

suggest a way which can be help full in selenium

I want to locate the element using java code 
i.e. Driver.findelement(by. ....

Comment: use this css selector "div.qooxdoo-table-cell"

Comment: yup but i have to use style property bcoz  there are many element having the same class name and that i don't have idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the element isn't unique you must grab both attributes:

This is the general form, replacing the empty strings for your required class and style:

```
driver.findElement("By.xpath(//div[@class='' and style='']");
```

So:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='qooxdoo-table-cell' and style='left:252px;width:117px;height:24px;']");
```

Best of luck!

Comment: You missed `"` before `By.xpath` in the first code snippet.. `driver.findElement("By.xpath(//div[@class='' and style='']");` not `driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class='' and style='']");`

Answer (score 4):

If you need to match `<div>` with exact `style` attribute, you can try something like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='qooxdoo-table-cell'][@style='left:252px;width:117px;height:24px;']"))
```

Comment: yup but i have to use style property bcoz there are many element having the same class name and that i don't have idea

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use cssSelector as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[style='left:252px;width:117px;height:24px;']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a older version of selenium you can as well use the older version of cssSelector.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[style='left:252px;width:117px;height:24px;']")
```

Note: this function still works in current version of Selenium (with DeprecationWarning )